# Twitter unable to render Card preview

Tags: twitter, share

I have an issue on Twtter sharing, I'm unable to share pages of my site, on Twitter card validator I have this log:

> INFO:  Page fetched successfully
>  INFO:  10 metatags were found
>   **WARN:  Not whitelisted**

PS : All Twitter meta tags exist.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Resolved.
The problem was on my code.
If any one has the same issue, you will need to check if you have any null value on you code.

Comment: Can you explain that? What do you want to mean with "any null value on your code"?